# Save loop output in a data file

Tags: export, files-and-directories, procedural-programming, save

I started working on *Mathematica* today. I'm trying to save the result of a loop in a file as a column, very simple to do, but hard for someone who doesn't know *Mathematica* syntax. Here is my code:

```
For[i = 1/10, i <= 4, i += (1/1000), 
    l = NIntegrate[(-1 + 0.707106781186547`/(-x^2 E^-x^2 + 0.5`)^0.5`)/x, {x, ∞, i}];
    Save["data.dat",l]
]
```

but obviously, this code is not working, it seems `Save` only works with strings. I have tried data streams, but I'm getting aborted each time I try.

**How can I save the output from [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) into a data file, in a loop?**

Comment: Changed the data.dat for a string with the same name and It's working, but the file has in each row a l=value. Is there a way to just save the value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to avoid `For` loops. And why not just use `Export`? And try to not use `l` for variable. Not a good choice as it looks like `1`.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
ClearAll[x];
range = Range[1/10,4,1/10];
data  = NIntegrate[(-1+0.707106781186547`/(-x^2 E^-x^2+0.5`)^0.5`)/x,{x,Infinity,#}]&/@range;
Export["data.txt",data]
```

This is how the file looks like

[image]

**Update**

For Fortran format use

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
ClearAll[x];
range = Range[1/10,4,1/10];
data  = NIntegrate[(-1+0.707106781186547`/(-x^2 E^-x^2+0.5`)^0.5`)/x,{x,Infinity,#}]&/@range;
data  = FortranForm[#]&/@data ;

Export["data.txt",data]
```

The file looks like

[image]

Comment: Hi, u are totally right, those mistakes are from a noob like me! By the way, I need the last values without that format because they are not readable in other languages like python, for example. Is there an easy way to change that?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by  __I need the last values without that format__ ? Can you give an example of what you mean?  Do you mean Python does not understand `-5.626766190483531*^-8` ?

Comment: Sure, those values are not readable in other languages like python (number*^ exponent) Python functions struggle with that syntax. Is there a way to write those values for example like 1.0232e-4, which is readable in python?

Comment: @nosumable update for Fortran format. Hopefully Python can read it now.

Comment: Thanks! U are awesome, that is what I was searching too! Have a good day.